# Angular material timepicker

Tags: angular, angular-material, timepicker, angular15

Is there an angular material component like this? [link](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-time-picker-edupala-akcez4?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

This component is not working on Firefox.

I need to have the same functions and a step of 30 minutes.

How can I do?

Comment: I know this one https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dhutaryan/ngx-mat-timepicker

Answer (score 1):

based on [CanIUse](https://caniuse.com/?search=input%20time)

The input type time is supported from Firefox 57-119. However, **input type week and month is not supported.**

Regarding to your angular material inquiry, there is no angular material timepicker, there is only datepicker